# url helper for namespace nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem. To use the gem, you do not need to create an activities controller for it. So I did not. However, I do have a comments controller. I want to have the following url helper for the comment's create action:

```
public_activity_activity_comments_path(@activity)
```

I have tried two things in my routes and both have failed. First, I tried using a namespace route:

```
  namespace :public_activity do
    resources :activity do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
```

This produces the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant PublicActivity::CommentsController:
```

Since I do not have a PublicActivity::Activities controller, I tried this instead:

```
get '/public_activity/activity/:activity_id/comments/new', to: 'comments#new'
post '/public_activity/activity/:activity_id/comments', to: 'comments#create'
```

However, this does not seem to produce any url helpers at all, as it gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `public_activity_activity_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f868e1b7760>:0x007f868e1afd58>:
```

The reason why I want a route like that is because in my comments view, the commentable can be any model, so I prefer to have a polymorphic form:

```
<%= form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  ...
```

Am I out of luck? Will I have to hardcore the url for form_for?

Comment: One option may be to do something like this using :as, post '/public_activity/activity/:activity_id/comments', to: 'comments#create', as: 'public_activity_activity_comments'. But I am hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Are you trying to comment on the activity (tracked by PublicActivity)?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you only need to play with your polymorphic association and form, `Public_Activity` will record the activities if you correctly configure that **any model** of yours.